# Greenplum COUNT(DISTINCT) produces different results for identical iterations of a query on a static dataset

Tags: sql, greenplum

I am using a Greenplum db (v 6.22.1) running PSQL (v 9.4.26) on a small linux server. I am analyzing ~36 million rows of data distributed among 6 segments. I want to count the unique number of users per month, with a fairly straightforward query:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS no_users
FROM users_table
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

As expected, I get output that looks like this:

| month | no_users |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 490005 |
| 2022-09-01 | 510015 |

However, when I rerun the query above (with no changes to data), I get the following result:

| month | no_users |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 490020 |
| 2022-09-01 | 510001 |

This happens every time the query is rerun, with no obvious pattern between the results each time. I have rebuilt the table as well as reuploaded the data to no avail. Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this problem? I have resorted to googling "Greenplum broken" but as anticipated that has not got me far.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` to make code clearer.

Comment: what is `with no changes to data`? do you mean `SELECT month, COUNT(user_id) AS no_users FROM users_table GROUP BY month ORDER BY month`

Comment: @RF1991 I just mean that the data hasn't been updated. I.e. I am expecting to get exactly the same result, but that is not what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Update the greenplum. The bug is fixed in [this issue](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/issues/14993).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) users_table;
```

Check data distribution over segments:

`SELECT count(*) c, gp_segment_id FROM users_table GROUP BY 2;`

Double-check that the query result equals your COUNT(*) :

```
select sum(c) from (SELECT count(*) c, gp_segment_id FROM users_table GROUP BY 2) x;
```

should equal :

```
select count(*) from users_table;
```

Comment: The counts you suggested match, but I'm still getting the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Can you try this please: SELECT month::date, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS no_users
FROM users_table
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month